# Qt- How to use connect between incompatible signal and slot

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I am trying to do a game. In this I want to call a function, that function will receive a point . But this function should be invoked by a timer's timedout signal.  Can anybody say how to achieve this. Below is the required/error code

```
Point p(a,b);

connect(timer,SIGNAL(timedout()),this,startDestruction(p));
```

Can anybody say how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a method to use as an intermediate slot, like this.

```
Point p(a,b);
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timedout()), this, q);

q() {
    startDestruction(this->p)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your design is flawed;

- you create p on stack
- you want Qt to prevent this object from dying and reuse it whenever a signal is called

Comment: You haven't seen the declaration for his startDestruction method, it could very well copy p.

Comment: start destruction is called when the signal is emitted not synchronously.

Comment: your comment made to get the insight of signal,slot mechanism. So that both must be compatible is a rule.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is usually solved by using [`QSignalMapper`](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qsignalmapper.html), but that only supports `QString`, `int`, `QWidget*`, and `QObject*` as parameter types.

If you want to use other types, you need to implement your own signal mapper (don't you hate how Qt doesn't let you make class templates derived from `QObject`s? :) like this:

```
class PointSignalMapper : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit PointSignalMapper( QObject * parent=0 )
        : QObject( parent ), m_map() {}

    void setMapping( QObject * sender, const Point & p ) {
        if ( sender )
            m_map[sender] = p;
    }

public Q_SLOTS:
    void map() {
        map( sender() );
    }
    void map( QObject * sender ) {
        if ( !sender )
            return;
        const QMap<QObject*,Point>::const_iterator
            it = m_map.constFind( sender );
        if ( it != m_map.constEnd() )
            emit mapped( it.value() );
    }
Q_SIGNALS:
    void mapped( const Point & p );

private:
    QMap<QObject*,Point> m_map;
};
```

Usage:

```
PointSignalMapper * mapper = new PointSignalMapper( this );
connect( mapper, SIGNAL(mapped(Point)), this, SLOT(pointDestroyed(Point)) );

mapper->setMapping( qObject1, point1 );
connect( qObject1, SIGNAL(timedout()), mapper, SLOT(map()) );

mapper->setMapping( qObject2, point2 );
connect( qObject2, SIGNAL(timedout()), mapper, SLOT(map()) );

// ...
```

In your specific case:

```
Point p(a,b);
PointSignalMapper * mapper = new PointSignalMapper( this ); // added
mapper->setMapping( timer, p );                             // added
connect( timer, SIGNAL(timedout()), mapper, SLOT(map()) );  // added
connect( mapper, SIGNAL(mapped(Point)),                     // modified
         this, startDestruction(Point)) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You usually have to create an intermediate slot that is triggered by the timer and then calls startDestruction with the point.

Comment: In your case it will be easier to make p a member variable, so startDestruction() can access it inside itself.  Is that possible with your design?

Answer (score 0):

How about redesign your class, so that startDestruction() is a slot of p. While p.startDestruction() is call, it'll emit a signal to notify the main class.

```
connect(timer,SIGNAL(timedout()),p,startDestruction());
connect(p,SIGNAL(destroyed()),this,destroyHandle());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's working, not-so-minimal example.

Qt requires that the mocked QObject-derived class is not in the main file, and that's why *Pipe* is separated. Using object as the wrapper instead of a function gives greater flexibility and does not require you to encapsulate variable in a field (no architecture changes).

**Output**

```
Destroyed target at [40, 12]
Destroyed target at [41, 11]
Destroyed target at [42, 10]
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "Game.h"
#include "Pipe.h"

#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QTimer>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    Game game;
    Point target(40, 12);
    Pipe pipe(&game, &target);

    pipe.pass();
    QTimer::singleShot(500, &pipe, SLOT(pass()));
    QTimer::singleShot(1000, &pipe, SLOT(pass()));
    QTimer::singleShot(2000, &app, SLOT(quit()));

    return app.exec();
}
```

**Game.h**

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H

#include <iostream>

struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;

    Point(int _x, int _y) : x(_x), y(_y) {}
};

class GameInterface {
public:
    virtual void startDesturction(Point * pt) = 0;
};

class Game : public GameInterface {
public:
    virtual void startDesturction(Point * pt)  {
        std::cout<<"Destroyed target at ["<<pt->x<<", "
                 <<pt->y<<"]"<<std::endl;

        //shift
        pt->x += 1;
        pt->y -= 1;
    }
};

#endif // GAME_H
```

**Pipe.h**

```
#ifndef PIPE_H
#define PIPE_H

#include "Game.h"

#include <QObject>

class Pipe : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Pipe(GameInterface * game, Point * target)
        : QObject(), m_game(game), m_target(target) {}
    virtual ~Pipe() {}

public slots:
    void pass() {
        m_game->startDesturction(m_target);
    }

private:
    GameInterface * m_game;
    Point * m_target;
};

#endif // PIPE_H
```