# pyqt: connect signal dynamically with user-supplied variables?

Tags: python, qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4

I create a dialog with a custom class:

```
d = ModifyRect(ctrl_name, rect_name)
```

It is shown modelessly. When it is accepted or rejected, I want to call a function on my MainWindow passing in these two variables, i.e. this slot should be called:

```
@QtCore.pyqtSlot("QString","QString")
def modifyRectAccepted(self, ctrl_name, rect_name):
    #foo
```

How do I go about connecting `d`'s `accepted` to my `MainWindow`'s `modifyRectAccepted`, passing in those 2 parameters? Or even, connect the two, but at least pass the `ModifyRect` instance in so I can grab them from there.

in pygtk this is pretty simple - you can pass more variables into `connect` and they are forwarded, and in any case the emitting widget is always passed in. What's the equivalent concept in PyQt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do that directly. You need to use signal mapper or intermediate slot. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840462/qt-how-to-use-connect-between-incompatible-signal-and-slot/5840573) answered a few days ago.

Or, if you're just interested in the source of the signal, use QObject's `sender()` method.

**EDIT:**
To use closures as intermediate slots you must use the [New-syle](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/new_style_signals_slots.html) signal and slot paradigm. This way is more pythonic and lets you specify any callable. Like this:

```
d = ModifyRect()

l = lambda: modifyRectAccepted(ctrl_name, rect_name)
d.accepted.connect(l)

def modifyRectAccepted(self, ctrl_name, rect_name):
    #foo
```

Comment: can i make an intermediate slot that is a closure?

Comment: can you show me how? how would i connect it? as i understand it i need to specify a slot name with `SLOT()`, and it has to be on the mainwindow.. so how do i just give it an anonymous/inner function as a slot?

Comment: ah brilliant.. i thought i had to go through qtcore.connect, which was lame